# find_first_of for a unicode special character in a string by use of its byte

Tags: c++

I'd like to do this, e.g

```
size_t pos=wStr.find_first_of(L"U+8001");
```

But the gnu compiler keeps warning the character is too long. I don't know what character 0x8001 represents but that's its encoded byte.

Comment: [The warning didn't appear in Wandbox, gcc.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/DkYUBmg05WigHKAC)

Comment: Neither `std::string` nor `std::wstring` are suitable for handling unicode, and neither are the standard library functions. If you need to do more than storing an printing the screen, use a library like ICU.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Show complete warning message.

Comment: What is the type of `wStr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try `size_t pos=wStr.find_first_of(L"\u8001");` to search for the character U+8001.

Comment: @MikeCAT, don't you mean L"\x8001"?

Comment: I tried but it fails. it produce a value long long after the search

Comment: @MegumiBear - then your data doesn't contain it.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your problem.  Create a simple program, use the answer by MikeCAT, and prove to yourself that your wStr variable is correct and contains what you expect.  For example...

```
std::wstring wStr(L"HELLO\u8001World");
auto aaa = wStr.find_first_of(L"\u8001");
std::cout << aaa;
```

You should also use the debugger, step to the location and look at the variable's contents.